# Avoiding loops when filling a sparse matrix

Tags: r, sparse-matrix, adjacency-matrix

I am dealing with a quite large sparse matrix (1.000.000 * 1.000.000) for my master's thesis. I use R and more precisely the 'Matrix' package dedicated to this issue.

Basically, my question is: ***Are there existing techniques to fill a sparse matrix without looping over the whole pre-existing dataframe I build the sparse matrix upon ? Is there a more efficient way to extract the indices where my sparse matrix will not take value 0 ?***

I'm not the first to ask this question, but most threads concern Matlab or Python, and I didn't find a clear answer.

Let's take an example to shed some light on the issue.

Suppose I have a data frame Df of this form:

```
list1 <- list("a","b","c")
list2 <- list("b,c","c", NA)
Df <- data.frame(cbind(list1, list2))
Df
  list1 list2
1     a   b,c
2     b     c
3     c    NA
```

I want to build a sparse matrix S that assigns S[i,j]=1 if Df[j,1] appears in Df[i,2]. Thus the matrix S would be of this form:

```
S=matrix(c(0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0), nrow=3)
S
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    0    1    1
[2,]    0    0    1
[3,]    0    0    0
```

Is it possible to fill this matrix without writing a loop that scans through each row and column of Df ?

Indeed, at the moment, my code would look like something like this:

```
row_vector <- vector()
col_vector <- vector()
val_vector <- vector()

count = 0

for (i in 1:3){
  for (j in 1:3){
    if (grepl(Df[i,1], Df[j,2], fixed=TRUE)==TRUE){
      count=count+1
      col_vector[count]=i
      row_vector[count]=j
      val_vector[count]=1
    }
  }
}
```

This is fine when I have a small matrix, but might get quite tedious with big matrices.

I hope I was clear enough. I would be grateful for any help or advice.

Regards,
Germain

Comment: Can you use valid R syntax to share you sample data? I've very confused by your "matrix" `M`, what does the dash represent?  Why do there seem to be different numbers of columns? Are `b` and `c` strings? If you say I have a matrix `M = matrix(c(1, 2, 3, 4), nrow = 2)` there is no ambiguity. You can share the syntax to create it, or if you have an suitable (and small) object in your workspace, just share `dput(M)`.

Comment: is `M` what you've created as `Df`?

Comment: Gregor, I've edited my question. It should be clearer now.

@Spacedman Yes indeed. I've edited my message accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You have to read documentation before asking such question - `?sparseMatrix`.

You need to provide 3 vectors to the constructor - row indices, column indices and values. Now you need to think how to get indices and values from your data.

Comment: I've been coding in R for a month now, so I'm clearly no expert. I'm not sure I get your message, though. I understand what a sparse matrix is and I have scanned through the documentation. I think the point of my question is precisely: can I get indices and values without looping over my entire data frame? How do experienced coders usually work this out?  Perhaps there's something I'm missing.